# How to call an angular $scope function using href in angular-kendojs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-kendo

I am new to angular-kendo.js. I want to call a function emailClick() from href ie.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" k-on-click = "emailClick()">Email</a>
```

and my controller and route is as follows :

```
app.controller('ContactCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'appSvc',
 function($scope, $rootScope, appSvc) {
    $scope.emailClick = function() {
        appSvc.selectItem = 'email';
        appSvc.back = true;
        $rootScope.go('email', 'slideLeft');
    };
 }]);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
        function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'partials/home.html',
                controller : 'HomeCtrl'
            }).when('/email', {
                templateUrl : 'partials/email.html',
                controller : 'ContactCtrl'
            }).otherwise({
                templateUrl : 'partials/home.html',
                controller : 'HomeCtrl'
            });
        }]);
    }());
```

Now on clicking Email I should go to the function `emailClick()` but it is not happpening. there is no error and no response. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `ng-click` directive,

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click = "emailClick()">Email</a>
```

Comment: ok thank you it finally worked with the above technique. The mistake I did was that I mentioned `emailClick()` function in different controller.